# mysql left join, how to write such query?

Tags: mysql

I have

first:

```
select url from urls where site = '$value' order by url
```

second:

```
select id, widget_name from widgets where display_urls LIKE 'urls.url' and is_father=1 order by id
```

Third:

```
select id, widget_name from widgets where display_urls RLIKE 'urls.url' and is_father=0 order by id
```

Fourth:

```
select id, widget_name, father_widget from widgets where father_widget = 'widgets.id' order by id
```

The fourth query must only take widgets.id from second query
the second and third queries take the value of urls.url from the first query

how to write all those in one mysql query using left join ?

Thanks in advance for your answers :)

Comment: urls.url os the same for second and third

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data and a resultset you'd like to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  w.id, w.widget_name, c.*
FROM    urls
JOIN    widgets w
ON      w.display_urls LIKE urls.url
        OR w.display_urls RLIKE urls.url
LEFT JOIN
        widgets с
ON      c.father_widget = w.id
        AND w.display_urls LIKE urls.url
        AND w.display_urls NOT RLIKE urls.url
WHERE   site = $value
ORDER BY
        url
```

This will select children only for those widgets that are `LIKE` but nor `RLIKE` the corresponding `url`.

Comment: Oops! not working it have to start with select url from urls right?
and I need two joins I want the results from RLIKE 'urls.url' and is_father=0 and from LIKE 'urls.url' and is_father=1